# Two separate gauge wired switch in one double gang box

Tags: lighting

I finished my  basement using 12/2 wire. In the furnace room I built, there is an existing pull string light with 14/2 gauge wire. I added another light in that same room using 12/2 wire. My question is can I use a double Gang Box to have two light switches, one for the 14/2 wired light and one for the 12/2 wired  light? Although they are both separately wired to their own switch using two different gauge wire they will be in the same box. Anybody know the rule or code on this?

Answer (score 8):

They can be in the same box but the breaker that feeds the switch and light with the 14/2 has to be a 15 Amp breaker. No exceptions. you might want to leave a note in the panel as to why the 12/2 is breakered at 15 AMPS. If that circuit needs to be 20 amps, you'll have to replace the 14/2 with 12/2.

Comment: Please leave the note: think of how much future-you would find it useful, versus the little now-effort to write it.

Comment: Thank you. The 14/2 is on a 15 amp. The 12/2 is an added run from finish job it is on a 20 amp.

Comment: Also, if two separate circuits are in the same box you *must not* join their neutrals.

Answer (score 1):

You're always allowed to use bigger wire than is required.  This being a 15A circuit, you need to use 14 AWG.   12 AWG is larger, so you're allowed to use it.

Remember the year is past 2011, so any *switch loops* must be wired with /3 cable. That precludes controlling 2 switches on the same /3 cable.